# Can I move an AWS Lambda site to a private domain?

Tags: flask, lambda, zappa

I'm using Zappa to deploy a Flask app.  It works ([site](https://b1829cjcs9.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev)).  Obviously I'd like to not have it stuck behind the aws domain and put it on my personal domain.

Everything I'm searching keeps talking about hosting a Lambda site *with* S3 and API Gateway.  Is there no way to just deploy my little app to a custom domain?

**Edit**

Following @mislav's answer, I was able to get my google domain working with AWS.  But when I try to finish by running `zappa certify` I get an error about the domain existing:

> raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
>   botocore.errorfactory.BadRequestException: An error occurred
>   (BadRequestException) when calling the CreateDomainName operation: The
>   domain name you provided already exists.

My `zappa_settings.json` is

```
{
"dev": {
    "app_function": "ping_app.app",
    "aws_region": "us-west-1",
    "profile_name": "Breuds",
    "project_name": "breuds",
    "runtime": "python3.6",
    "s3_bucket": "zappa-ping-redshift",
    "slim_handler": true,
    "certificate_arn": "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:010174774769:certificate/3a92c204-5788-42fc-bc65-74aaae8c1b3f",
    "domain": "breuds.com"
}
}
```

I am beginning to think I am doing something convoluted on my domain side.  I'm using Google Domains (since I have a custom domain for my email, just using that), but that seems to cause a headache trying to get AWS to talk to it.

Comment: If it has only static content and client side javasript then you can host it on S3 and setup your domain using Route 53.  If you have some backend logic then you would need to use api-gateway and lambda

Comment: I guess I'm confused why I need api gateway.  Aren't I just hitting a url already?

Comment: Lambda functions cannot respond directly to HTTP requests.  That's why you need the API gateway to properly handle HTTP traffic.

Comment: What is the correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s actually explained in [zappa’s readme](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/blob/master/README.md#deploying-to-a-domain-with-aws-certificate-manager).

> Deploying to a Domain With AWS Certificate Manager
>
> Amazon provides their own free alternative to Let's Encrypt called AWS Certificate Manager (ACM). To use this service with Zappa:
>
> Verify your domain in the AWS Certificate Manager console.
>   In the console, select the N. Virginia (us-east-1) region and request a certificate for your domain or subdomain (sub.yourdomain.tld), or request a wildcard domain (*.yourdomain.tld).
>   Copy the entire ARN of that certificate and place it in the Zappa setting certificate_arn.
>   Set your desired domain in the domain setting.
>   Call $ zappa certify to create and associate the API Gateway distribution using that certificate.

There are also instructions to use your existing certificate etc.

Don’t let it fool you, the title of the section makes it sound like it’s only about certificates, but there are detailed instructions regarding using you own domain.

Edit:
I’m including [my own zappa settings](https://github.com/mislavcimpersak/xkcd-excuse-generator/blob/master/zappa_settings.json) for reference.

```
{
    "common": {
        "app_function": "app.__hug_wsgi__",
        "aws_region": "eu-central-1",
        "s3_bucket": "excuse-generator",
        "profile_name": "mislavcimpersak",
        "remote_env": "s3://excuse-generator/secrets.json",
        "certificate_arn": "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:500819636056:certificate/3edb9c1c-12c5-4601-89a9-dc42df840fa6"
    },
    "prod": {
        "extends": "common",
        "domain": "function.xkcd-excuse.com"
    },
    "dev": {
        "extends": "common",
        "debug": true,
        "keep_warm": false,
        "domain": "function-dev.xkcd-excuse.com"
        }
    }
```

---

**Step by step guide for domain bought on namecheap.com and served through cloudflare.com**

1. buy domain on namecheap.com/use existing
2. register new site on cloudflare.com/use existing
3. cloudflare will give you (most probably) two nameservers
4. enter under https://ap.www.namecheap.com/domains/domaincontrolpanel/xkcd-excuse.com/domain DNS - choose "Custom DNS" nameservers given on cloudflare
5. go to AWS ACM and request a new certificate (certificate must be created in **us-east-1** region)
6. enter if necessary multiple subdomains (`foo.example.com` & `foo-dev.example.com`)
7. make note of ACM ARN given from AWS management console
8. in `zappa_settings.json` enter under `certificate_arn` your ARN
9. in `zappa_settings.json` under `route53_enabled` put `false` - **this is a must**
10. in `zappa_settings.json` under `domain` enter domain for each stage ie. `foo.example.com` and `foo-dev.example.com`
11. run `zappa certify <stage_name>`
12. it should say: "Created a new domain name with supplied certificate. Please note that it can take up to 40 minutes for this domain to be created and propagated through AWS, but it requires no further work on your part.
    Certificate updated!"
13. go to CloudFlare DNS interface and enter

    - CNAME: foo - i3jtsjkdeu4wxo.cloudfront.net
    - CNAME: foo-dev - d2jtsjkdeu4wxo.cloudfront.net
14. wait for 40 minutes and check your domain(s), they should serve your Lambda function

Comment: I've been trying to replicate this.  When I run `zappa certify` I get an error around domain existence: "botocore.errorfactory.BadRequestException: An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the CreateDomainName operation: The domain name you provided already exists."

Of course it exists?

Comment: can you share your `zappa_settings.json` file?

Comment: Question updated.  Definitely feels like I'm getting closer

Comment: I've updated my answer with a *step by step guide*. I'm using namecheap and cloudflare in my guide, but you should be able to make it work with domain managed with Google Domains.

Comment: I see that you are missing `route53_enabled` in your zappa_settings.json file and.... you have to wait +40 minutes for domains to work.

Comment: Ok, after a lot of trial and error, I realized I had set up the certificate in my region (us-west-1) and that I needed to delete it (not just add another one in us-easy-1).  Now the zappa commands all run flawlessly.  But still no site.
I suspect it's b/c Google Domains uses their DNS and I need to specify them, just haven't figured out how yet.

Comment: yeah, sorry. don't have anything on google domains, can't help you there. but please check #13 in my answer, maybe it will help you in some way

Answer (score 1):

You might not need API Gateway.  It will depend on site functionality.  You can host a static website using S3 with a custom domain.  You can include client-side javascript(angular/react etc..)   API Gateway is really for handling http requests and passing it on to defined resources(Lambda or others).

If your site will require backend capability then you have few options.

 1) Build lambda functions and then use API Gateway(REST API) to interact with these functions. 

yourhostname.com -> S3 -> API Gateway(aws hostname) -> lambda

2) Use AWS JS SDK to interact with your lambda functions directly.
   
yourhostname.com -> S3 -> AWS SDK -> lambda

3) Use API Gateway and then forwarding to Lambda or self hosted web server(flask node) using EC2 instance

yourhostname.com -> API Gateway(aws hostname) -> lambda

yourhostname.com -> self hosted web server

Here is a picture that might make it a bit clearer. 
[image]

Correct me if I am wrong flask is used for backend development to build microservices.  To host it you would use either build lambda functions or host it on your own instance. 
https://andrich.blog/2017/02/12/first-steps-with-aws-lambda-zappa-flask-and-python/

Let me know if this helps.